# Trouble cooking steak to the standard internal temperature

Tags: temperature, steak

[image]

I just cooked a steak following Gordon ramsey's "perfect steak" method found on youtube, I flipped the steak every minute about 4-5 times on medium-medium high heat, but I couldn't get the internal temperature to go higher than 120 degrees F and I've always had this problem regardless of how I cook the meat.

I'm including a picture of a cut from about the thicker part of the steak, it seems like it's medium-rare to me but again it only went to 120 degrees according to my thermometer which is a metal rod type thermometer.

I should note, I let the steak sit out for about an hour before cooking so it could reach room temperature, after that I put it in a zip-lock bag and let it sit under hot water for a minute or two hoping to further increase the temperature so it would cook quicker, also room temperature in my house is about 70 degrees or so.

I don't know what else to do, I don't want to eat completely brown steak, I did eat this steak despite the thermometer saying the internal temp only hit 120 and it was great, but nobody in my house but me would eat it like that. So any suggestions would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I would first ask:  is your thermometer correct?  Calibrate it in ice water and boiling water.

Comment: I'll go test it in boiling water and report back.

Comment: Tested it in boiling water, the temp didn't quite hit the "boiling point" mark on the dial but it was only off by maybe 4 degrees or so.

Comment: So you know you have a 4 degree error at 212 F.  now I would test ice water.  If it is the same 4 degrees in the same direction, you know how to adjust.  If the difference varies by temperature, you have a tougher row to hoe.  The next question would be technique on how you are measuring, what type of thermometer you have, and how long you give it to stabilize.

Comment: It's a metal rod with a dial at one end, a bit like the thermometers you put under your tongue I suppose but for meat. I stuck it into the center and let it sit until the temperature seemed to stop moving about a minute or so.

Comment: This is an analogue thermometer, not a digital one? Typically the analogue ones need a fair bit of probe embedded in the meat, often almost an inch. Meaning they're not too useful for steaks...

Comment: It seems accurate in ice water the needle hit just above the "freezing point" mark on the dial about 31-32 degrees.

Comment: Can you suggest a good digital thermometer then and can anyone tell how well done the steak is from the photo?

Comment: That photo looks about 130-135 F in the middle to me. But that is not an accurate way to take temperatures :-)  Thermapens are considered the best of the breed for instant read thermometers, but are expensive; a decent Taylor instant read should do the trick.

Comment: I'm curious why others in the house wouldn't eat that steak.  Did they think it was over- or under-cooked?

Comment: My mom has it in her head that any pink in any meat is horribly bad for you, whenever we cook steak I have to make it so it's as brown as possible in the center or she and my sister won't bother to eat anything but the brown outer edges.

Comment: Don't feed steak to these ladies... :-)   Seriously, you will never get anything but the outside browned.  The inside might turn grey and well done around 165 F, and will be tough and rubbery, but it will never be brown.

Comment: When you tested your thermometer, did you have just the tip in the water like you would have had just the tip in the steak?

Comment: No I submersed about 2 inches of the rod.

Comment: I suggest joining us in chat.  Don't mind the resident lunatics.  http://chat.stackexchange.com/  Assuming you have enough rep to get in, not sure what the threshold is.

Comment: Says I need 20 rep.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things that could be going on here:

- cut: not all steak cooks at the same rate. Really tender cuts cook faster than some of the tougher, more flavorful cuts, increasing cooking time by up to 50%. Cuts like tenderloin, filet, and loin (US) - Sirloin (UK) are more tender and cook faster. Denser cuts like sirloin, top sirloin, and bottom sirloin (US) and rump (UK) cook slower. If you are cooking a denser cut then you simply need to cook it longer.
- Pan heat: Most chefs have really good stoves that produce load of heat, most mere mortals have average stoves which aren't as powerful. Medium heat on a professional, or very high quality stove is hotter than the medium heat on an average stove, so try cranking it up to full blast. Also, make sure your pan is fully up to temp. I cook my steaks on a cast iron skillet, and I let it heat up for 10 minutes before I start frying steak
- Heat contact: even though steak is full of fat it takes some time for this to start working, so coating your steak with a bit of vegetable oil (not olive oil, it burns at high temperatures) will make sure it gets good heat contact

So my advice would be to get the pan hotter and cook it longer. Try adding one more minute per side.

EDIT:
@kenny says that he is cooking loin, so assuming it's 3/4", or 2cm thick and looking for medium done-ness I would cook the first side for 5 minutes and then the second side 3 minutes. The uneven times are to make sure it cooks evenly. So you need a total of 8 minutes cooking time. I don't do the flip every minute method because the uneven times work for me, and it lets me do other prep.

Comment: Alright, well I'm cooking the other two steaks this evening, I just did this one this morning for a practice run. I'll try just cooking them on high heat.

I was under the impression though that if you want the inside cooked more thoroughly you should cook on lower heat otherwise the outside burns before the inside reaches temperature?

Comment: There are many factors, you have how much heat your stove produces, how well the pan conducts it, and how thick your steak is. Your steak doesn't look that thick, if the heat isn't high enough you won't get much browning on the outside. For thick steaks I keep it lower for the reasons you stated.

Comment: Say @Kenny, what cut are you using, and how thick?

Comment: I believe it's loin, it was very tender also.